# Oracle functionality Set Channel partner Rating system logic through Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to add `rating system` in my below query with the following **three** criteria:-

```
select  ev.LOGIN_NAME Introduced_By, to_char(cp.CREATION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
 Entry_Date,  cp.DATE_OF_INTRODUCTION, cp.NAME_OF_FIRM, cp.PERSON_NAME, cp.EMAIL_ID, cp.MOBILE,
cf.SR_NO Followup_SrNo, cf.FOLLOW_UP_TYPE, cf.ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION, cf.NEXT_FOLLOW_UP_DATE, 
cf.NEXT_TO_DO_ACTIVITY, cf.COMMEN Comments
from XXCUS.XXACL_PN_NEW_CHA_PART cp, XXCUS.XXACL_PN_NCP_FOLLOWUP cf, XXCUS.XXACL_PN_EMPLOYEE_V ev
where cp.mkey=cf.mkey(+) and cp.created_by=ev.USER_ID
--and cp.created_by in (13581)
and cf.FOLLOW_UP_DATE between '01-jun-2015' and '14-aug-2015' --DATE_OF_INTRODUCTION --cp.CREATION_DATE
order by cp.CREATION_DATE , ev.LOGIN_NAME,  cp.DATE_OF_INTRODUCTION, cf.NEXT_FOLLOW_UP_DATE ;
```

**CRITERIA**

1. *A rating - has done booking - valid for 6 months from the date of booking. After 6 months if he has enquiry, he moves to B category, if he does not have enquiry, he moves to C category. And he gets booking, he retains his rating as A*
2. *B rating - Has enquiry - Valid for one month. If next month he does not have enquiry, he automatically moves to C category. If booking is done, he moves to A category, if he has enquiry next months he retains his rating as B.*
3. *C category No enquiry or Booking*

Please suggest as I am new to Oracle and how to implement it. Also let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for A - rating

```
select 
ab.broker_id, sum(CASE 
WHEN SYSDATE - la.creation_date <= 180
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) rating 
FROM xxacl_pn_new_cha_part ab, xxacl_pn_lease_det ld,xxacl_pn_leases_all la 
WHERE ab.broker_id = ld.broker_id 
and ab.mkey=la.mkey(+) 
group by ab.broker_id
```

for B -rating

```
SELECT ab.broker_id, sum(CASE 
WHEN SYSDATE - cef_dt <= 30 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) rating 
FROM xxacl_pn_new_cha_part ab, xxcus.xxacl_pn_customer_enquiry_v ce 
WHERE ab.broker_id = ce.broker_id 
group by ab.broker_id
```

Comment: remove *** before and after case statement and re-execute

Comment: removed, now getting error as `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE`

Comment: what are the datatype for cp.DATE_OF_INTRODUCTION and cf.NEXT_FOLLOW_UP_DATE columns . i have assumed they have date datatype .in case if they are not convert them to date using to_date( ) function and re execute

Comment: akshya: can you tell me which table it is coming from. Sorry I am new to this that's y asking such stupid question

Comment: got it: the datatype is `date`

Comment: Not a problem ,XXCUS.XXACL_PN_NEW_CHA_PART has column DATE_OF_INTRODUCTION and XXCUS.XXACL_PN_NCP_FOLLOWUP has column NEXT_FOLLOW_UP_DATE .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89257/discussion-between-nadeem-and-akshay-joshi).

Comment: hi akshay, can you come on chat.

Comment: hi akshay, do let me know once you come back on chat.

Answer (score 0):

You must somehow define attributes *last_booking_date* and *has_enquiry* from your data.

If you manage this (I'm not able to interpret your select) the classification can be done as follows:

```
 select last_booking_date, has_enquiry,
  case when months_between(trunc(sysdate), last_booking_date) < 6 then 'A'
       when has_enquiry = 'Y' then 'B'
       else 'C' end as classification
 from tst; 

 LAST_BOOKING_DATE   HAS_ENQUIRY CLASSIFICATION
 ------------------- ----------- --------------
 10.09.2015 00:00:00 Y           A              
 12.02.2015 00:00:00 Y           B              
 12.02.2015 00:00:00 N           C
```

Comment: can you tell me what do you want to define attributes ? or what data you want from my side

Comment: **You** must define where in your database the date of the last booking is stored (is it `DATE_OF_INTRODUCTION`?) and how to decide if there is an enquiry or not.

Comment: i have another table for enquiry

Comment: any help sir related to this ??

Comment: well not realy, you must joint the enquiry table in your query and use the enguiry column in the case statement as shown in my answer...